# Не работает автодополнение в sublime text 3 Anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublime-text, anaconda

В sublime text 3 не работает автодополнение кода с помощью плагина Anaconda, просто в один момент перестало работать. Подсказывали методы библиотеки, а щас просто ничего.
(код Python)

Answer (score -1):

В папке `C:\...\Sublime Text 3\Packages\Anaconda` создаешь (если его нет) файл Anaconda.sublime-settings и прописываешь в нем `{ "auto_complete_triggers": [{"selector": "source.python - string - comment - constant.numeric", "characters": "."}] }`